# cmmi old delta type1

Tags: fonts, type1

I noticed that in Math into LaTeX pdf file, (it's mil.pdf from 
[CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/mil))
appears the old delta `\delta` from cmmi font family, that one which Donald Knuth has substituted in 1991: see

http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cm.html

I wonder if it still exists (or even if it ever existed in a public version) this font, i.e its *.pfb file.
[image: the type1 old delta]

Comment: Maybe to generate the font metatype has been used

Comment: for quite a long while, the type-1 version of the cm fonts were distributed with the "old" delta.  this was only corrected in (i think) 2008.  it would be hard to find that version now though.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There is a version of 1997 of cmmi*.pfb with the current new delta. I wonder if metatype has been used to create the font used in mil.pdf.

Comment: the only type-1 versions of the cm fonts that i know about are the ones that were (are?) identified as "bluesky" and those corrected for knuth's 70th birthday (which was in 2008; mentioned earlier).  if there are others, i don't know how they were created.